# Make NERDTree Bookmark open load configuration from local directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there any way to make it so that when you open a bookmark in NERDTree that it will search for a .vimrc in that directory and source its contents? I use exrc to enable per directory .vimrc files to provide overrides on a per project basis. Currently if I use the bookmarks within NERDTree to switch to another project, the configuration files are not loaded. So I either have to manually source these files or open a new vim instance from within the new projects directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your local `.vimrc` files don't work because you don't `:cd` at the same time you open the bookmark.

With `set exrc`, local `.vimrc` files are looked for in the *current directory* which doesn't change by default: if you start Vim from `~`, no matter how many files you open anywhere on your machine, the current directory will still be `~`.

Luckily, there is a NERDTree-specific solution:

```
let NERDTreeChDirMode=2
```

and a more generic one:

```
set autochdir
```

Both options do more or less the same thing: they change the *current directory* to the parent of the opened file.

What do you put in those local `.vimrc`s? Did you consider using modelines?

Comment: The problem is that vim uses a .vimrc from the folder where you launched it. Even if I just cwd inside of vim without NERDTree it doesn't work. And if I do use cd in NERDTree to move the working directory. It continues to use the vimrc from the directory where it was launch. This is the piece I'm trying to overcome.